# Using JOLT is it possible to remove duplicate elements in sub array?

Tags: json, jolt

I'm new to JOLT and I'm trying to remove duplicate elements in the enty_func array and pick the latest element. Inside this array, enty_func_id is a unique key. I tried a lot using the map function but I'm stuck. I would really appreciate it if some can help me out on this.

Below are my input and output. I tried the map function but it is not working. The below spec is partially done.

### INPUT

```json
{
  "authrzd": [
    {
      "authrzd_mbr_id": "101",
      "enty_func": [
        {
          "enty_func_id": "20",
          "func_typ": "EDIT",
          "enty_typ": "CONTACT",
          "auth_acs_ind": "1",
          "src_commit_ts": 20211028170625.689991
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "authrzd_mbr_id": "102",
      "enty_func": [
        {
          "enty_func_id": "20",
          "func_typ": "EDIT",
          "enty_typ": "CONTACT",
          "auth_acs_ind": "1",
          "src_commit_ts": 20211028170625.689991
        },
        {
          "enty_func_id": "10",
          "func_typ": "VIEW",
          "enty_typ": "EDIT_TEST",
          "auth_acs_ind": "1",
          "src_commit_ts": 20211028170625.689991
        },
        {
          "enty_func_id": "20",
          "func_typ": "EDIT",
          "enty_typ": "CONTACT",
          "auth_acs_ind": "1",
          "src_commit_ts": 20221028170625.689991
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### SPEC

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "authrzd": {
        "authrzd_mbr_id": {
          "*": {
            "enty_func": {
              "*": {
                "enty_func_id": "enty_func_id",
                "@": "@(enty_func_id)"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

### OUTPUT

```json
{
  "authrzd": [
    {
      "authrzd_mbr_id": "101",
      "enty_func": [
        {
          "enty_func_id": "20",
          "func_typ": "EDIT",
          "enty_typ": "CONTACT",
          "auth_acs_ind": "1",
          "src_commit_ts": 20211028170625.689991
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "authrzd_mbr_id": "102",
      "enty_func": [
        {
          "enty_func_id": "20",
          "func_typ": "EDIT",
          "enty_typ": "CONTACT",
          "auth_acs_ind": "1",
          "src_commit_ts": 20221028170625.689991
        },
        {
          "enty_func_id": "10",
          "func_typ": "VIEW",
          "enty_typ": "EDIT_TEST",
          "auth_acs_ind": "1",
          "src_commit_ts": 20211028170625.689991
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is using **cardinality** transformation with **ONE** option in order to pick the leftmost element of the array which's formed through combination of `authrzd_mbr_id` and `enty_func_id` attributes such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "authrzd": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&",
          "enty_func": {
            "*": {
              "@": "&2.@(3,authrzd_mbr_id).@(1,enty_func_id)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "enty_func": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "enty_func": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&.authrzd_mbr_id",
          "*": "&1.&2[]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "authrzd"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

**Edit** : If your aim is to pick the latest element(object) of the array, then replace the **cardinality** spec with the following **modify-overwrite-beta** spec

```json
{
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "enty_func": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=lastElement(@(1,&))"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Man, you saved my life @Barbaros :) and I really appreciate your quick response. Can we take the latest duplicate record(i.e. enty_func_id) based on the src_commit_ts? this JOLT spec is taking the first element. I have updated the question.

Comment: How nice @AdityaKonda, thank you too. I've just edited as you desired.